# Getting the value of child node in xml using groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

How do I parse the value of Profile in the below xml using groovy?

```
<Books>
        <Book>
                <Profile>Science</Profile>
                <Extension>.png</Extension>
                <Length>1920</Length>
                <Width>1080</Width>
        </Book>
        <Book>
                <Profile>English</Profile>
                <Extension>.png</Extension>
                <Length>640</Length>
                <Width>460</Width>
        </Book> 
</Books>
```

I have tried:

```
def bookxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(bookText)
def profile = bookxml.Book.findAll { it.Profile }
```

but this is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work well - if the syntax is corrected `parseText` instead of `parsexml` - all the profiles are found.

Catch the sample:

```
def bookXml = '''<Books>
        <Book>
                <Profile>Science</Profile>
                <Extension>.png</Extension>
                <Length>1920</Length>
                <Width>1080</Width>
        </Book>
        <Book>
                <Profile>English</Profile>
                <Extension>.png</Extension>
                <Length>640</Length>
                <Width>460</Width>
        </Book> 
</Books>'''

def bookxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(bookXml)
bookxml.Book.findAll { it.Profile }.each { println it.Profile.text() }
```